# How to find in Java if JToggleButton is pressed

Tags: java, swing

How to find in Java if JToggleButton is pressed and if it is pressed to set to be unpressed ?

Comment: why? when? do you really mean "pressed" (an intermediate state of the ButtonModel in the process of "clicking") or "selected" (which is the end result of "clicking") As you see from the wide range of the answers, your question is not precise enough. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

All such things you can get from [ButtonModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html).

[getModel()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getModel%28%29).isPressed()

Answer (score 3):

Have you try the `isSelected()` method ?

Answer (score 3):

or inside `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {...}` is possible to check

```
AbstractButton abstractButton = (AbstractButton) event.getSource();
boolean selected = abstractButton.getModel().isSelected();
```